# Donde está el error en este código?

Tags: javascript

Debo empezar preguntando cuánta gente hay en el grupo familiar.
Crear tantos inputs+labels como gente haya para completar la edad de cada integrante.
Al hacer click en "calcular", mostrar en un elemento pre-existente la mayor edad, la menor edad y el promedio del grupo familiar.Pero tengo este error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Tarea Clase 6</title>
</head>
<body>

    <label>Número de integrantes</label>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Ingresa la cantidad" id="cantidadFamiliares">
    <label>Ingresar</label>
    <button type="button" id="boton-ingresar">Ingresar cantidad</button>

    <div>

    </div>

    <button type="button" id="boton-calcular">Calcular</button>

    <p><em id="mayor"></em></p>
    <p><em id="menor"></em></p>
    <p><em id="promedio"></em></p>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="tarea-clase-6.js"></script>
</body>
</html>



const nodoDiv = document.querySelector('div');

function crearNodos(cant) {
    const nodoDiv = document.querySelector('div');
    for (let i=0; i < cant; i++) {

        const nuevoLavel = document.createElement('label');
        const textoLavel = document.createTextNode(`Edad integrante n° ${i+1}`);
        nuevoLavel.appendChild(textoLavel);
        nodoDiv.appendChild(nuevoLavel);

        const nuevoInput = document.createElement('input');
        nuevoInput.placeholder = 'Ingresa la edad aquí';
        nodoDiv.appendChild(nuevoInput);
    }
}

function calcularMenorMayor(arr) {

    let max = arr[0];
    let min = arr[0];

    for (let i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        if (max <= arr[i]) {
            max = arr[i];
        }
        if (min >= arr[i]) {
            min = arr[i];
        }
    }
}

function calcularPromedio(arr) {

    let suma = 0;
    let promedio = 0;

    for (let i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        suma += arr[i];
        promedio = suma/arr.length;
    }

}

const botonIngreso = document.querySelector('#boton-ingresar');

botonIngreso.onclick = function() {

    const cantidadFamilia = Number(document.querySelector('#cantidadFamiliares').value);

    crearNodos(cantidadFamilia);

}

const botonCalcular = document.querySelector('#boton-calcular');

botonCalcular.onclick = function() {

    const edades = document.querySelectorAll('input');
    let arrayEdades = [];
    for (let i=1; i<edades.length; i++) {
        arrayEdades.push(Number(edades[i].value));
    }

    calcularMenorMayor(arrayEdades);
    calcularPromedio(arrayEdades);

    document.querySelector('#mayor').innerText = `La mayor edad es ${max}`;
    document.querySelector('#menor').innerText = `La menor edad es ${min}`;
    document.querySelector('#promedio').innerText = `El promedio de edades es ${promedio}`;

}
```

Comment: Deberias agregar tu HTML

Comment: @MiguelZarate los backticks son permitidos en JS ([ver aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47067353/5587982)), de hecho son útiles para combinar cadenas y variables sin necesidad de estar concatenando con el punto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas declarar las variables max, min y promedio como globales asi:

```js
const nodoDiv = document.querySelector('div');
let max = 0;
let min = 0;
let promedio = 0;

function crearNodos(cant) {
    const nodoDiv = document.querySelector('div');
    for (let i=0; i < cant; i++) {

        const nuevoLavel = document.createElement('label');
        const textoLavel = document.createTextNode(`Edad integrante n° ${i+1}`);
        nuevoLavel.appendChild(textoLavel);
        nodoDiv.appendChild(nuevoLavel);

        const nuevoInput = document.createElement('input');
        nuevoInput.placeholder = 'Ingresa la edad aquí';
        nodoDiv.appendChild(nuevoInput);
    }
}

function calcularMenorMayor(arr) {

    max = arr[0];
    min = arr[0];

    for (let i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        if (max <= arr[i]) {
            max = arr[i];
        }
        if (min >= arr[i]) {
            min = arr[i];
        }
    }
}

function calcularPromedio(arr) {

    let suma = 0;
    
    for (let i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        suma += arr[i];
        promedio = suma/arr.length;
    }

}

const botonIngreso = document.querySelector('#boton-ingresar');

botonIngreso.onclick = function() {

    const cantidadFamilia = Number(document.querySelector('#cantidadFamiliares').value);

    crearNodos(cantidadFamilia);

}

const botonCalcular = document.querySelector('#boton-calcular');

botonCalcular.onclick = function() {

    const edades = document.querySelectorAll('input');
    let arrayEdades = [];
    for (let i=1; i<edades.length; i++) {
        arrayEdades.push(Number(edades[i].value));
    }

    calcularMenorMayor(arrayEdades);
    calcularPromedio(arrayEdades);

    document.querySelector('#mayor').innerText = `La mayor edad es ${max}`;
    document.querySelector('#menor').innerText = `La menor edad es ${min}`;
    document.querySelector('#promedio').innerText = `El promedio de edades es ${promedio}`;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Tarea Clase 6</title>
</head>
<body>

    <label>Número de integrantes</label>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Ingresa la cantidad" id="cantidadFamiliares">
    <label>Ingresar</label>
    <button type="button" id="boton-ingresar">Ingresar cantidad</button>

    <div>

    </div>

    <button type="button" id="boton-calcular">Calcular</button>

    <p><em id="mayor"></em></p>
    <p><em id="menor"></em></p>
    <p><em id="promedio"></em></p>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="tarea-clase-6.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que las variables `min, max, promedio` no están en el contexto del `onclick`.

Para evitar declarar esas variables como globales, puedes retornar los valores desde las funciones, así las usas únicamente cuando las necesites.

En ese caso, desde `calcularMenorMayor()` puedes devolver un objeto con el mayor y el menor. Entonces la llamada sería así:

```
    var minMax=calcularMenorMayor(arrayEdades);
```

Y para obtener cada dato: `minMax.min` y `minMax.max`

En cambio, desde `calcularPromedio()` puedes retornar el promedio, recuperándolo en el contexto:

```
    var promedio=calcularPromedio(arrayEdades);
```

Por ejemplo:

```js
const nodoDiv = document.querySelector('div');

function crearNodos(cant) {
    const nodoDiv = document.querySelector('div');
    for (let i=0; i < cant; i++) {

        const nuevoLavel = document.createElement('label');
        const textoLavel = document.createTextNode(`Edad integrante n° ${i+1}`);
        nuevoLavel.appendChild(textoLavel);
        nodoDiv.appendChild(nuevoLavel);

        const nuevoInput = document.createElement('input');
        nuevoInput.placeholder = 'Ingresa la edad aquí';
        nodoDiv.appendChild(nuevoInput);
    }
}

function calcularMenorMayor(arr) {

    let max = arr[0];
    let min = arr[0];

    for (let i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        if (max <= arr[i]) {
            max = arr[i];
        }
        if (min >= arr[i]) {
            min = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return {min:min, max:max};
}

function calcularPromedio(arr) {

    let suma = 0;
    let promedio = 0;

    for (let i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        suma += arr[i];
        promedio = suma/arr.length;
    }
    return promedio;

}

const botonIngreso = document.querySelector('#boton-ingresar');

botonIngreso.onclick = function() {

    const cantidadFamilia = Number(document.querySelector('#cantidadFamiliares').value);

    crearNodos(cantidadFamilia);

}

const botonCalcular = document.querySelector('#boton-calcular');

botonCalcular.onclick = function() {

    const edades = document.querySelectorAll('input');
    let arrayEdades = [];
    for (let i=1; i<edades.length; i++) {
        arrayEdades.push(Number(edades[i].value));
    }

    var minMax=calcularMenorMayor(arrayEdades);
    var promedio=calcularPromedio(arrayEdades);

    document.querySelector('#mayor').innerText = `La mayor edad es ${minMax.max}`;
    document.querySelector('#menor').innerText = `La menor edad es ${minMax.min}`;
    document.querySelector('#promedio').innerText = `El promedio de edades es ${promedio}`;

}
```

```html
    <label>Número de integrantes</label>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Ingresa la cantidad" id="cantidadFamiliares">
    <label>Ingresar</label>
    <button type="button" id="boton-ingresar">Ingresar cantidad</button>

    <div>

    </div>

    <button type="button" id="boton-calcular">Calcular</button>

    <p><em id="mayor"></em></p>
    <p><em id="menor"></em></p>
    <p><em id="promedio"></em></p>
```

---

## Recomendaciones sobe el ámbito de las variables

Me permito hacerte una recomendación sobre el ámbito de las variables. Yo declararía en el ámbito global del DOM **todas las referencias a los elementos**, mientras que las variables como `min, max, promedio` las retornaría desde sus funciones.

El problema es que cada vez que haces llamadas del tipo `document.querySelector('#mayor').innerText` haces una consulta al DOM para que seleccione ese elemento y al mismo tiempo lo modificas. Lo mismo ocurre si fuera para obtener su valor con `value`. Es mejor crear la referencia una sola vez con algo como: `const elMayor=document.querySelector('#mayor');` en el ámbito global y luego, si necesitas modificar ese elemento en cualquier parte, usar `elMayor.innerText="Texto"`. O sea, algo parecido a lo que haces con `nodoDiv`.